# How to run Mongodb as a service with authentication on a windows machine

Tags: windows, mongodb

remark: I am using win10. 
My goal is when windows boot mongodb as a service with authentication start( you can not enter the database without authenticate) but I can not manage to do it on a windows machine ( in linux it worked)
I write here the steps I tried:

1. dowlnload MongoDB
2. change conf from default to the following

```
# mongod.conf
  http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: C:\MongoDB\Server\4.0\data
  journal:
    enabled: true

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path:  C:\MongoDB\Server\4.0\log\mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1

security:
    authorization: enabled
setParameter:
   enableLocalhostAuthBypass: false
```

3. create a Admin user in the Admin collection.

db.createUser(
   {
     user: "....",
     pwd: "...",
     roles:
       [
         { role: "root", db: "admin" }
       ]
   }
)

4. Made it a service:

```
sc.exe create MongoDB 
binPath=“\”C:\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin\mongod.exe\” 
–service
config=\”C:\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin\mongod.cfg\”” DisplayName= “MongoDB” start= “auto”
```

getting feedback Successful.
but when i restart the computer, mongod is not starting and if i dont specify `mongod --auth` i can still enter without a authentication
How can I run Mongod as service with authentication? what am i doing wrong?
When i am trying to activate the service manually I get the following error
[Error photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7v2e.png)

Comment: you can create a task in task scheduler and make your batch file as a windows service

Comment: yes, using the task scheduler is an option, but i will much prefer avoiding it, and use the run it as a service with authentication

Answer (score 3):

The issue with the security tag. I have the same issue when I wanted to start the service in Windows 10. I copy the command from Windows service properties and then run on the command prompt.

The prompt shows me the error:

> Unrecognized category : security

I found the solution and it is to write the security tag with options properly.

YAML need some specific input I guess. Here it is the solution.

```
security:
    authorization: enabled
```

Comment: Tab is not working for me. I used double space  in the start and space in the middle. MongDB V4.2

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue.

In your mongodb.cfg, use 2 spaces (instead of TAB) to indent **authorization: enabled**

Comment: 2 spaces are not mandatory. Single space or 4 spaces all works. TAB is the problem.